# Error: cannot find variable AppTheme_Dark_Dialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a login activity in android studio and I keep getting this error:

> error: cannot find symbol variable AppTheme_Dark_Dialog

How do I resolve this error?

This is my styles.xml file :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog" />
```

Comment: post your style.xml code where you are defining the style ??

Comment: I guess you used some sample code from somewhere and didn't notice that you need to define that in your styles.xml file.

Comment: I've added my style.xml

Answer (score 1):

Go into the layout editor, select where it most likely says `App theme` and look for another one. There are a lot of themes even on dark. Further, it is just Holo.Dialog unless you want the light theme which is Holo.Light.Dialog. Holo.Dark.Dialog is the same as Holo.Dialog as far as I can tell.

To set it, find the style xml files and set:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
```

In the normal style.xml that is not defined with v11 and v14, just blank in Android studio.

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

You may want to look into AppCompat as well, as it allows the use of e.g. material design before API 21. And it saves time compared to manually writing layouts for the different versions

Comment: I added this to my styles.xml file,  but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Which is what exactly?

Comment: What exactly is your error that pops up when using that code?

Comment: error: cannot find symbol variable AppTheme_Dark_Dialog

Comment: Do you write it like AppTheme.Dark.Dialog?

Comment: I'm very new to android and I'm using a template. I'm just getting that one error.

Comment: Use Theme.Holo.Dialog instead. That was the entire point. Do not use AppTheme.Dark.Dialog if it doesnt work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115924/discussion-between-ankita-kedia-and-polarbear0106).